# Invalid string or buffer length error while executing SP with TVP using pyodbc

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

Using TVP executing a stored procedure in python with pyodbc.

TVP:

```
    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[SID_TBL] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SId] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
```

Stored Procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GET_STUS] 
    @sid_type dbo.SID_TBL READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select * from dbo.TAB_NAME WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE SID IN (SELECT SId FROM @sid_type) 
END
```

Code to execute the stored procedure:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

uid = "admin"
pwd = "abcd1234"
connection_string = (
    r"DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;"
    r"SERVER=xxx;"
    r"DATABASE=xxx;"
    f"UID={uid};PWD={pwd};"
)
con = pyodbc.connect(connection_string, autocommit=True)
cur = con.cursor()

s_ids = ["SID_TBL", "dbo"]
a = cur.execute("SELECT TOP 1000 SID FROM TAB_A WHERE <conditions>").fetchall()
ids = list(enumerate([row[0] for row in a]))
s_ids.extend(ids)


sql = "EXEC dbo.GET_STUS @sid_type=?"
params = (s_ids)
result = cur.execute(sql, params).fetchall()

print(pd.DataFrame(result[:100]))
```

Experiencing the error while executing the stored procedure
Error: pyodbc.Error: ('HY090', '[HY090] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length (0) (SQLBindParameter)')

Not able to figure it out why this error is throwing. Any insights will help to resolve this issue.

I can see this issue is still open with [pyodbc package](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/520) but, when i tried this with Jupiter notebook its working with out any issue. It is strange that its happening when tried with any editor (using pycharm).

Comment: Is there a full traceback error?

Comment: No even after the printing entire traceback its printing just the line what i posted

Comment: Perhaps try `SELECT TOP 1000 SID … ORDER BY SID DESC`